# Allow voting to close as self-duplicate... user created a new account

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

We often see that new users ask the same question over and over again, the first question is too broad, lacks any code, etc. Instead of editing that post, the new user creates a new question. Sometimes this is done due to lack of understanding, sometimes to circumvent the rules. The current system allows to vote to close such questions as duplicate, even if it hasn't received an (upvoted) answer.

It also happens the new user creates a new account and post the exact same question, like we wouldn't notice.

We suddenly can't vote to close as duplicate any more. This is a problem for users yielding the dupe-hammer.

What can we do in such cases? Should we be able to vote to close as duplicate anyway, and on what conditions?

Comment: I thought you *could* close another post by the same user as a dupe even if their previous one didn't meet the usual requirements... See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341107/closed-question-as-duplicate-of-unanswered-question-by-same-user, that allowance is already there (on SO, at least?)

Comment: Oh my, I messed up. The user in the case I tried create a new account, sigh.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Updated the question.

Comment: when exact same question (text wise) is posted from a different account, this possibly can be flagged for moderators as suspected plagiarism (formally it probably qualifies)

Comment: @gnat Indeed, but flagging takes moderator time (which might be unavoidable in some occasions). I do however think that closing such questions quickly will remove the incentive to make multiple accounts.

Comment: @PatrickHofman plagiarism, as well as asking from duplicate accounts, are probably issues worth mod time (and requiring mod intervention anyway)

Comment: I lost you. How is the author account related to closing as duplicate? We can use dupe hammer whenever there is proper tag, period. Author of the questions (both source and target) is not relevant at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this seems to be about questions having no answers - these can't be used as dupe targets, neither by dupehammer nor even by moderators. The only exception is when these are asked from the same account

Comment: @gnat A moderator can close a question as a duplicate even if the target has no answers, even if they are asked from two different accounts (partly to address this exact situation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just flag for moderator attention.  Someone is using multiple accounts to subvert site features.  That's abusive behavior meriting their attention. They'll be able to close the question and also consider whether any other actions might also be merited.

Comment: Yeah. That was what I got from the comments too. That it takes more time is the one thing that bothered me. That's why I hoped holders of the dupe hammer could help out.